# Das Fenster kippen/ankippen - Unterschied

Tags: prefix

Wenn ich mich nicht irre, man kann ein Fenster sowohl kippen als auch ankippen. Wo liegt aber der Unterschied?

Comment: Ich habe "das Fenster ankippen" noch nie gehört. Das heißt nicht, dass es nicht Familien gibt, die so einen Ausdruck benützen. Aber ich wüsste ebenfalls nicht zu sagen, wo der Unterschied zwischen "kippen" und "ankippen" liegen sollte. (Anders als bei "das Brot schneiden" und "das Brot anschneiden", was geringfügig unterschiedliche Dinge bezeichnet.)

Comment: Im Duden steht (als Beispiel): die Fenster sind angekippt. http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ankippen

Comment: Da, wo ich lebe (SW), sagt man "gekippt", und wer "angekippt" sagt, outet sich als *Reigschmeckter".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kippen bedeutet die Lage zu ändern. Wenn ein Gegenstand gekippt wird fällt er letztendlich in seine neue Lage (umkippen). Das kann bedeuten, dass er umfällt oder auch durch einen Andchlag nur teilweise kippt.
Ankippen ist das Ändern der Lage um eine kleinen Winkel wobei ein Fall nicht möglich sein sollte.

Ankippen ist also einerseits eine geringere Bewegung, vor allem wird aber nicht das umkippen erzielt. Beim Kippen erreicht das Objekt die neue Lage. Neben einem Objekt kann übrigens auch die Situation kippen. Auch hier ist es aufwändiger die Ausgangslage wiederherzustellen.

Es mag lokale Unterschiede geben, aber da die Lage des Fensters nur gering geöffnet wird wird es angekippt.

Comment: Und wie wäre es mit dem Beispiel mit Fenster? Wenn man das Fenster etwas aufmachen will sagt man: Bitte kippe das Fenster ? oder kippe das Fenster an? und dann ist es angekippt oder gekippt?

Comment: Ich kenne das Wort *ankippen* gar nicht. Ich kippe das Fenster.